# WPF RibbonTab - cannot bind to RibbonTab Headerstyle

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I try to customize the RibbonTabHeader with different colors.
However I'm unable to bind dynamic values to the object RibbonTabHeader. One can customize its style by assigning a style to HeaderStyle. But the get of the binded method BackgroundColor is never called.

Xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ribbon:RibbonTab}">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}" />
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding GroupDataCollection}" />
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding IsVisible}" />
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsEnabled}"/>
            <Setter Property="HeaderStyle">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ribbon:RibbonTabHeader}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding BackgroundColor}"/>     
                    </Style>
                </Setter.Value>
             </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#333333" />
        </Style>
```

Code behind:

```
    public string BackgroundColor
    {
        get { return "Black";  }
    }
```

When I create the style dynamically in the code behind and assign it to HeaderStyle it is actually working. But this doesn't seem to me as an option as my style will become much more complicated (I have to remove gradients, paint a horizontal rectangle, adjust borders, ..). So  it  will get complicated to create all dynamically in the code behind.
The other bindings that are directly called in RibbonTab i.e. IsEnabled are actually working.

What is working is this code:

In Xaml:

```
  <Setter Property="HeaderStyle" Value="{Binding Style}"/>
```

In the code behind:

```
  public Style Style
  {
        get
        {
             Style style = new Style(typeof (RibbonTabHeader));

             style.Setters.Add(new Setter(RibbonTabHeader.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Green));
             return style;
         }
   }
```

Any ideas how I can bind dynamic values to the object RibbonTabHeader ?

I was thinking of defining a style in the xaml and then load it via LoadResource in the codebehind. But I'm not sure if I can clone it later to assign all different colors to different tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of research I still didn't find a propper answer to my  question.

I nevertheless found a workaround to make it work.
What I finally did is to us a CustomConverter to exploit the tab name that is dynamically bound.

The Converter that is returning a different color based on each tab name looks like this:

```
public class TabNameToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value.ToString() = "tabName")
            return "Red";

        return "Black";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The Xaml looks like this (Content is the name of the Tab, it is replacing the background color)

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Converters:TabNameToColorConverter x:Key="TabNameToColorConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type ribbon:RibbonTabHeader}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Content,Converter={StaticResource TabNameToColorConverter}}"/>
</Style>
```